# xamarin android: Hamburger menu items disappear when app is built in release

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When i build my xamarin.forms app in debug for android, i see the hamburger menu items, however as soon as i build in release mode, they disappear. This is specifically occuring in the android project,im using masterdetailpages, and this happens in the master page.
any help will be appreciated. The following is the code the master page:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"      x:Class="myApp.ViewAndViewModels.BookMasterDetailPageMaster"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myApp.ViewAndViewModels;assembly=myApp"
             Title="☰" BackgroundColor="#91D8F7">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView"
              SeparatorVisibility="None"
              HasUnevenRows="true"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <ListView.Header>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#91D8F7">
                <Image x:Name="AppImage" BackgroundColor="#91D8F7"></Image>
                <Label Text="Menu" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="31">
                       <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Alvi Nastaleeq" />
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Alvi Nastaleeq.ttf#Alvi Nastaleeq" />
                                        <On Platform="UWP">/Assets/Fonts/Alvi Nastaleeq.ttf#Alvi Nastaleeq</On>
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
<Grid Grid.Row="1" ColumnSpacing="0" >

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" 
                                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                                     Spacing="0"
                                     Margin="0,0">
                          <Image Source="{Binding IconImageSrc}" WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="32"></Image>

                          <Label Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="30">
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Alvi Nastaleeq" />
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Alvi Nastaleeq.ttf#Alvi Nastaleeq" />
                                        <On Platform="UWP">/Assets/Fonts/Alvi Nastaleeq.ttf#Alvi Nastaleeq</On>
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>        
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class BookMasterDetailPageMaster : ContentPage
    {
        public ListView ListView;

        public BookMasterDetailPageMaster()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AppImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("myApp.Assets.MainMenuIcon.png");


            BindingContext = new BookMasterDetailPageMasterViewModel();
            ListView = MenuItemsListView;
        }

        class BookMasterDetailPageMasterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public ObservableCollection<BookMasterDetailPageMenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
            public ImageSource IconImageSource { get; set; }

            public BookMasterDetailPageMasterViewModel()
            {
                IconImageSource = ImageSource.FromResource("myApp.Assets.Icons.articon.png");

                MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<BookMasterDetailPageMenuItem>(new[]
                {
                    new BookMasterDetailPageMenuItem { Id = 1, Title = "Menu1",IconImageSrc = this.IconImageSource,TargetType = typeof(Menu1) },
                    new BookMasterDetailPageMenuItem { Id = 2, Title = "Menu2", IconImageSrc = this.IconImageSource },
                    new BookMasterDetailPageMenuItem { Id = 3, Title = "Menu3", IconImageSrc = this.IconImageSource },
                    new BookMasterDetailPageMenuItem { Id = 4, Title = "Menu4", IconImageSrc = this.IconImageSource },

                });
            }

            #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            async void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
            {
                if (PropertyChanged == null)
                    return;

                //PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which version of xamarin.forms are you using?

Comment: Share full code

Comment: im using the xamarin version: 4.3.0.947036

Comment: i cant share full code, but i can share the masterdetail pages code. the problem is that it works fine when built in debug mode, but  not in release. I have tried to uncheck "enable optimizations" but with no effect.

Comment: You mean the listView in the master page is empty under release mode?

Comment: yes the menu items are not shown

Comment: I just test a master-detail page on my side and the menu item both work in debug and release mode. Maybe you have to check the dataSource at release mode? Try clean and rebuild? Or update your visual-studio?

Comment: okey ill have a check. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. In my particular case, i was using Dotfuscator for the xamarin android project in release, and as soon as i disabled this, the menu items started to show.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only answering cause I can't comment yet, so you can count this as a comment

You need to provide more information, code snippets or examples if you can't share your code.

Comment: I have added some code for the master page in the question, but i really dont know what to share more than that, this seems more like a configuration issue in release mode. Works perfectly in debug mode.